# Android Studio Out of Memory

Tags: macos, android-studio

This morning I have been experiencing an issue with Android Studio, whenever I open it I am getting the following error.[image: Android Studios Out of Memory error]

I have tried removing Android Studio and getting a clean install. Removing all the preference folders. Removing and re-downloading my project's repository. Creating a new project. All of these still end with this error showing up. No mater how high I increase the memory it is still getting this issue.

I have checked the Activity Monitor and it is actually only using 524mb of memory. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The next thing I'm going to try is using an older version of Android studios. Apart from that I'm not sure what else to do beside a clean install of the OS and hope for the best.

**UPDATE:**
Couldn't work out a way of fixing this, and had to perform a clean reinstall of OSX.

Comment: I had this to, had to reinstall and update Android Studio.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I was fighting with this problem today for a few hours and ended up trying File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... and chose the Invalidate/Restart option. Seems to have fixed the Out of Memory error.

Don't know if that will work for you at a later time, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I reinstalled Android Studio, deleted the ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview and ~/Library/AppSupport/AndroidStudioPreview, but this is the only solution that worked. +100!

Comment: Op needs to mark this as the answer. This worked for me as well

Comment: Worked so well for me!

Comment: It just wouldn't work for me. Last week it was working fine. I updated on Friday and since then I restart Studio every hour. Editted config uncountable times, increased all those configs. Reset all these and that. That thing still wouldn't behave

Comment: This helps but then I keep getting the error again and again. Did anyone else face the same issue? Please help me.

Comment: I have 8GB RAM still facing; after reinstall and deletion `.AndroidStudio4.0` and `.gradle` folder. It was started after the library update.

Answer (score 5):

Go to /Applications and do right click on Android Studio > show package contents
Then go to /Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions and change it like this:

-Xms128m

-Xmx800m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m

-XX:+UseCompressedOops

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways to handle out of memory in Android Studio:

1. Clean the Project And Rebuild
2. Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Sync Project with Gradle files
3. Restart the PC
4. Close Android Studio ->  Delete .idea folder -> Start the Android
   Studio and rebuild.
5. Still facing the issue, Need proper investigation.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a simple error in your code that Android Studio does not know how to resolve.

Example problem: In my case, within my activity's onCreate function, I wrote `binding.root.also{ }` and deleted the opening curly bracket of the also scope function. This caused Android Studio to run out of memory and freeze.

Solution: I deleted the also function within Notepad and there were no problems afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I entered /* to begin commenting out a few lines. And it happened before I could add the */ to close the comment section. Therefore, the entire second half of the file (and beyond) was being commented out. I could not go back to add the needed */ to close the comment, because the "Out of Memory" window kept popping back up before I could do so.

So I closed Android Studio,
opened the same .java file in NotePad,
added the needed * / a few lines below the /*,
saved the file with NotePad,
then reopened it again in Android Studio.

The Out of Memory problem was gone for good.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem in my case, I tried to dump memory and it is reached to 200mb and while opening the studio it is showing the continuous process, because of '.hprof' the file is loading. Finally, I removed the '.hprof' and able to run my project. The .'hprof' file removed from the directory ''

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error recently (Android studio 3) even though I had 16gb Ram + I7700K CPU.
I noticed that it started to appear after I disabled the Virtual Memory Ram because I needed some extra space in my SSD. so I just reactivated it and the problem was solved!