# Android Studio Error: Out of memory

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

Since 3 days comes every time when I start Android Studio a window with the tile "Out of memory".

[image]

What shall I do?

Can you help me?

Comment: Change **Xmx** Value to **1280** and press continue

Comment: Danke dir!!! :D

Comment: Komischerweise kommt der Fehler trotzdem immer :(

Comment: Please, update your AS to 2.3.2

Comment: Ok i update it!

Comment: Hello, it shows the error still :(

Comment: try 750 as value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Out of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850045/android-studio-out-of-memory)