# out of memory error when there is nothing but five images

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have 5 image buttons in a linear layout and have written no code other then what you start off with when you first create an android application.But for some weird reason Android studio claims i'm out of memory why?

Comment: What's the image dimensions and memory?

Comment: image dimensions are 57dp width and 57dp length all of them are the same

Comment: 5 * 4 * 57 * 57 = 64980 (about 65K). It should be fine. Try setting `android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: this usually happens when the image is pixel-based. Try to decrease the resolution of your images and it should work.

Comment: I was told not to use android:largeHeap="true" because they said "you should avoid requesting it to whatever extent possible"

Comment: Not a good advice with large heap...

Comment: You should starting to use some loading images library, like Picasso, Glide, etc. It will be useful for you in future.

Answer (score 0):

If Android *Studio* claims you're out of memory, this is related to your development environment, rather than the target Android device. Most likely, it's not physical memory, but the amount of memory the JVM (that runs Android Studio) is allowed to consume.

Try [invalidating the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850045/android-studio-out-of-memory):

- File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Or, try increasing the actual amount of [JVM heap](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html), under:

- Help -> Edit Custom VM Options