# Android Studio Out of Memory Error Within XML Editor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Using Android Studio on the XML editor and just received the error below. Unsure why and how I can resolve, but it is substantially impacting my development as it is popping up frequently:

[image]

Running MacOS High Sierra on a MacBook Pro Early 2015, 8 GB RAM so I don't understand why this is occurring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Out of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850045/android-studio-out-of-memory)

Comment: Grow java heap size to get rid of this problem. Use this command -Xms64m or -Xms64M to increase size. Follow this tutorial: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control

Comment: That popup tells you what to do, it says _"Please increase 'Xmx' setting and restart the IDE for change to take effect"_. Currently it is configured to use max 1280 MB of memory, and it turns out that is not enough, so you need to increase it.

Comment: Thanks, I have been using AS for roughly 2 years now and am curious as to why this is all of the sudden occurring. I have tried invalidating caches and restarting, deleting other applications that are consuming RAM, enabling power save mode, but the problem seems to persist. I will try and increase, but with 8 GB I don't see why this is happening in the first place, unless indeed Android Studio has grown to become a memory hog.

Comment: @ZubariaAshraf do I use that command within the AS terminal?

Comment: No, I am sharing a link, from where you can get the detail information how and where to execute that command. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config